# Access to the specific content of an inside code of a script

Tags: javascript

Please, can anybody tell me how can I access to the value of "41" in this inner script of a website? I just tried this, but it doesnt work

I tried with:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("back-in-stock-helper");
```

I only need the number 41, and the example code I need to access is this

```
<script id="back-in-stock-helper">
  var _BISConfig = _BISConfig || {};
  _BISConfig.product.variants[0]['inventory_quantity'] = 41;
</script>
```

Thanks!

Solved:

`var elem = document.getElementById("back-in-stock-helper");`

`var elem2 = elem.textContent;`

`var ult_pos = elem2.lastIndexOf('=');`

`var stock = elem2.substring(ult_pos);`

Comment: Why not access the value directly? `_BISConfig.product.variants[0]['inventory_quantity'] `.

Comment: If you're trying to do this textually, by looking at the source, the only **reliable** way is to use a JavaScript parser. There are several open source ones written in JavaScript.

Comment: Im trying to do that in a Chrome Browser extension, and when I try to get directly: the value, its gives me this error "myscript.js:2 (anonimous function)"